# People Picker count Document Library

Tags: list, javascript, people-picker

I want to count the People added to a People Picker field. In my Document library there should be a column "UserNumber" and in this column the Number of users of the People picker field for every Document in the Library should appear.

I have found this entry: [Count number of users in people picker using Javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91302/count-number-of-users-in-people-picker-using-javascript)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function GetUserCount() 
{ 
//Where "Multiple_Users_Field" may refer to name of the user field or the Title of Div can be retrieving from inspecting from browser
var PickerTitle = "Multiple_Users_Field"; 
var PickerDiv = jQuery('[id$="ClientPeoplePicker"][title="' + PickerTitle + '"]');
var PickerEditor = PickerDiv.find('[title="' + PickerTitle + '"]');
var PickerInstance = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[PickerDiv[0].id];
return  PickerInstance.TotalUserCount
}

alert( GetUserCount() );
```